# Conditions for fancy chapter title

Tags: conditionals, chapters, books

I use a `book` class and here is a part of my fancy title page for the `mainmatter` chapters.

```
\newlength\chapterwidth
\settowidth\chapterwidth{\huge\chaptertitlename}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\normalfont\filcenter}
{\tikz[remember picture,overlay]{
\node[fill=nicedarkblue,font=\sffamily\fontsize{96}{72}\bf\selectfont\color{white},anchor=north east, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=3.4cm] 
at ([xshift=-1cm,yshift=-1cm]current page.north east) 
(numb) {\thechapter};
\node[rotate=90,anchor=south,inner sep=4pt,font=\Huge\sffamily] at (numb.west) {Chapter};
}
}{20pt}{\scshape\Huge\color{nicedarkblue}#1}[\vskip10pt\Large***]
```

I do not master conditions in latex, but I would like to have four different styles:

- chapter in frontmatter
- chapter in mainmatter
- appendix in mainmatter
- chapter in backmatter

How to branch on these conditions ?

Comment: I would include a new `\titleformat` wherever I want a new title format to start... The `\titleformat` should act like a switch (similar to a font changing macro like `\bfseries` or `\itshape`), changing formatting from that point onward; so there's technically no "conditioning" required. A bigger question though: Why do you want to switch formats and not keep things consistent?

Comment: @How do I define other formats with `\titleformat`? For the bigger question, in fact I want to keep the same "global idea" but I want to change things like the "Chapter" word and the color of the node.

Comment: You could have a look on the `titlesec` package (the documentation contains some examples) or using the `KOMA` classes in order to change the titleformat.

Comment: What do you mean by saying "appendix in mainmatter"? There is a `\appendix` switch to be used to create appendecies. Shouldn't your third requirement be "chapter in appendix"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Generally speaking, rather than including "conditionals" in the title format to work out where in the document the title is used, you either (a) include macros in the format itself which will expand appropriately (e.g. `\chaptertitlename` which will be redefined once `\appendix` is given) or (b) redefine with a new `\titleformat` at the appropriate point in the document.

Since you didn't give a complete compilable MWE I'm guessing somewhat about your settings. But here's a short example. This is basically your code, but (a) instead of "hardcoding" the word "Chapter" in the bit that prints the colored box, I've used `\chaptertitlename` and (b) instead of hard-coding a color in the two places you used it, I put a macro which can therefore easily be redefined.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\newcommand{\chaptercolor}{blue}
\usepackage{tikz}

\titleformat{\chapter}
[display]
{\normalfont\filcenter}
{\tikz[remember picture,overlay]
  {\node[fill=\chaptercolor,%<--- Not hardcoded color
       font=\sffamily\fontsize{96}{72}\bf\selectfont\color{white},anchor=north east, 
       minimum width=3cm, 
       minimum height=3.4cm] 
       at ([xshift=-1cm,yshift=-1cm]current page.north east) 
         (numb) {\thechapter};
     \node[rotate=90,
           anchor=south,
           inner sep=4pt,
           font=\Huge\sffamily]
       at (numb.west) {\chaptertitlename};%<-- Not hardcoded "CHAPTER"
    }}
  {20pt}
  {\Huge\bfseries\color{\chaptercolor}#1}%< Not hardcoded color
  [\vskip10pt\Large\bfseries***]
\begin{document}

\frontmatter

\chapter{Preface}

\lipsum

\mainmatter\renewcommand{\chaptercolor}{red}

\chapter{Chapter}

\lipsum

\appendix\renewcommand{\chaptercolor}{green!40!black!60}

\chapter{Appendix Something}

\end{document}
```

[image: chapter in red] [image: appendix in green]