# Change white space in a word tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I need the word "Chapter" in the picture below to stop at bottom and top of the black square. The size of the letters in "Chapter" needs to be the same size as it is now, but I would like there to be eactra white space between each letter in the word.

```
\documentclass[oneside,10pt,oldfontcommands,standalone]{memoir}   
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{fix-cm}    


\makeatletter
\newcommand\HUGEr{\@setfontsize\Huge{50}{60}} 
\makeatother  

\usepackage{tikz}
\makechapterstyle{box}{
    \renewcommand*{\printchaptername}{}
    \renewcommand*{\chapnumfont}{\normalfont\sffamily\HUGEr\bfseries}
    \renewcommand*{\printchapternum}{
        \flushright
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw[fill,color=black] (0,0) rectangle (2cm,2cm) node[color=white]  (test) {};
        \draw[color=white] (1cm,1cm) node { \chapnumfont\thechapter };
        \draw[color=white] (-0.5,0) rectangle (-0.1,2) node[midway,rotate = 90,color=black] () {Chapter};
        \end{tikzpicture}
    }
    \renewcommand*{\chaptitlefont}{\normalfont\sffamily\HUGE\bfseries}
    \renewcommand*{\printchaptertitle}[1]{\flushright\chaptitlefont##1}
}
\chapterstyle{box}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Introduction}  
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Just add spaces between each letter of the word chapter `\draw[color=white] (-0.5,0) rectangle (-0.1,2) node[midway,rotate = 90,color=black] () {C h a p t e r};`

Comment: Maybe this anser can help you: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/169702/134144